# transform the result of rawQuery to an object

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Im trying to get an array of an Object and the query returns size 15, but inside it says "All objects are null". I don't know what im doing wrong. I googled a little bit but i didn't find anything.

```
public ArrayList<IngredientType> ingredientsTypeAll(){
        ArrayList<IngredientType> returnArray = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT code, cod_category, name FROM recipe_tags_master",null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            returnArray.add((IngredientType) this.cursorToEntity(cursor));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return  returnArray;
    }
```

and the Entity is this:

```
public class IngredientType {

    private int code;
    private int code_category;
    private String name;

    public IngredientType(int code, int code_category, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.code_category = code_category;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public int getCode_category() {
        return code_category;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what this call does:

```
(IngredientType) this.cursorToEntity(cursor)
```

In each iteration of your loop you must create a new `IngredientType` object and add it to the list:

```
public ArrayList<IngredientType> ingredientsTypeAll() {
    ArrayList<IngredientType> returnArray = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT code, cod_category, name FROM recipe_tags_master", null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        returnArray.add(
            new IngredientType(
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("code")),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("cod_category")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"))
            )
        );
    }
    cursor.close();
    return returnArray;
}
```

I also removed the initial call to `cursor.moveToFirst()`, because `while (cursor.moveToNext())` is enough.